# R - Replace the value of a specific position where there is a NA value

Tags: r, missing-data

**Given this data set:**

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 10, 10, 16, 21),
                 b = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2, 4))
```

| a | b |
| --- | --- |
| NA | NA |
| NA | NA |
| NA | NA |
| NA | NA |
| 10 | NA |
| 10 | NA |
| 16 | 2 |
| 21 | 4 |

**Calculate the differences of values between the previous row:**

```
df <- df%>%
  mutate(a_diff = a - lag(a, default = first(a)),
         b_diff = b - lag(b, default = first(b)))
```

| a | b | a_diff | b_diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NA | NA | NA | NA |
| NA | NA | NA | NA |
| NA | NA | NA | NA |
| NA | NA | NA | NA |
| 10 | NA | NA | NA |
| 10 | NA | 0 | NA |
| 16 | 2 | 6 | NA |
| 21 | 4 | 5 | 2 |

**But the result I need would be the following:**

| a | b | a_diff | b_diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NA | NA | NA | NA |
| NA | NA | NA | NA |
| NA | NA | NA | NA |
| NA | NA | NA | NA |
| 10 | NA | 10 | NA |
| 10 | NA | 0 | NA |
| 16 | 2 | 6 | 2 |
| 21 | 4 | 5 | 2 |

**That is, I need to replace the last 'NA' value of column 'a_diff' with the value corresponding to the row number of column 'a'. And the same with the 'b_diff' column.**

**Thank you in advance for reading my question and I would appreciate any clue you can give me to solve my problem.**

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is what you are looking for. Using `max(which(is.na()))` with your "diff" value will get the position of the last `NA` in that column. You can substitute with values for that particular row as below.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(a_diff = a - lag(a, default = first(a)),
         b_diff = b - lag(b, default = first(b))) %>%
  mutate(a_diff = ifelse(row_number() == max(which(is.na(a_diff))), a, a_diff),
         b_diff = ifelse(row_number() == max(which(is.na(b_diff))), b, b_diff))
```

**Output**

```
   a  b a_diff b_diff
1 NA NA     NA     NA
2 NA NA     NA     NA
3 NA NA     NA     NA
4 NA NA     NA     NA
5 10 NA     10     NA
6 10 NA      0     NA
7 16  2      6      2
8 21  4      5      2
```

Comment: Was the first intuition to use `max(which(is.na(a_diff....`, but then remembered `coalesce`+1.

Comment: @TarJae Ah yes, very nice answer.

Answer (score 2):

Perfect use case for `coalesce`:

```
library(dplyr)

df%>%
  mutate(a_diff = a - lag(a, default = first(a)),
         b_diff = b - lag(b, default = first(b))) %>% 
  mutate(a_diff = coalesce(a_diff, a),
         b_diff = coalesce(b_diff, b))
```

```
  a  b a_diff b_diff
1 NA NA     NA     NA
2 NA NA     NA     NA
3 NA NA     NA     NA
4 NA NA     NA     NA
5 10 NA     10     NA
6 10 NA      0     NA
7 16  2      6      2
8 21  4      5      2
```